# how to return a value from inner function that have a phonegap database SQLite query to the outer function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, android-sqlite

This is my code

```
hasSubAcc = function(accPid) {
    $.mobile.eazydb.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Account_Parent_ID="'+accPid+'"', [],
            function(tx, rs){
                if(rs.rows.length == 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
        });
    });
}
```

and the method accessed by

```
alert(hasSubAcc(accid));
```

this alert prints undefined. whats wrong with this code. Any solutions plz.Thanks.

Comment: Is there any error? Check the error log.

Comment: there is no error. it simply prints undefined and proceed

Comment: You could put your hasSubAcc code in a function and call it from the executeSQL() callback

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very clear, as you are using heavy process(i.e. database) inside a function so jquery runs this function in seperate thread parallel to your main thread now in this condition your value will always get undefined.

you can make a global variable `var hasSubAcc=-1;` now after checking condition

```
if(rs.rows.length == 0) {
                    hasSubAcc=0;
                } else {
                    hasSubAcc=1;
                }
```

now give a small delay using

```
setTimeout(function(){
alert(hasSubAcc);

},500);

or

while(hasSubAcc==-1){
//do nothing
}
alert(hasSubAcc);
```